# Remotely post to a Wordpress Blog with php (best solution)

Tags: php, wordpress, post, remote-access, xml-rpc

I am searching for the best solution to post to a wordpress blog from a php script on a different server.
Is there any good php script already developed?
I think it would not work with a cookie auth model like the WP REST API?

Thank you very much

Regards

memme

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Try to use auth1, and remove posts via WP REST.

Comment: I thought there might be a ready to use PHP script pack for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think best solution is to use the XML-RPC of wordpress with this PHP client:
https://github.com/letrunghieu/wordpress-xmlrpc-client

Here is the code to add a new Wordpress Blog Post and retrieve the URL:

```
    require_once 'WordpressClient.php';
    require_once('.\Exception\NetworkException.php');
    require_once('.\Exception\XmlrpcException.php');

    $endpoint = "http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php";
    $wpUser = 'username';
    $wpPass = 'password';
    $YourCategoryID = 5;
    $wpClient = new \HieuLe\WordpressXmlrpcClient\WordpressClient();
    $wpClient->setCredentials($endpoint, $wpUser, $wpPass);
    $title="Your Blog Post Title";
    $title = htmlentities( $title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    $body='Your HTML coded article';
    $content = array(
    'post_category' => array( $YourCategoryID ), // my category id
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $body,
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
);

    $result=$wpClient->newPost($title,$body,$content);
    $postname=$wpClient->getPost($result);
    $new_post_url_slug=$postname['post_name'];
```